# I am trying to create DMZ but I have problem with the wired and wireless

Tags: network, dmz

I am trying to create DMZ but I still have problem with wired and wireless connections. Especially when the manager's Laptop connects to wired and wireless?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
What is the best DMZ design for this diagram?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quick answer: Have a separate DMZ for servers and customers. The hotel manager needs a VPN to let them connect to the local network.

Comment: Could you please  explain more?

Comment: Do you mean I should create DMZ2 including customers and manager, and DMZ1 including servers ?

Comment: Yes - two DMZs, "Server DMZ" and "Customer DMZ". Sorry, on re-reading my original comment, it is not clear.

Comment: Thanks so much <  but what about the hotel manager laptop , is okay and secured if it is connected to wired and wireless from time to time ?

Comment: It's not ideal, but as long as the laptop has a firewall, it should be ok.

Comment: Ah alright, Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it , but could you please tell me about your perfect idea to solve this problem ? How can I make the manager's laptop connected to Wired and wireless in the most safest way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Manager connects to wireless only, then uses a VPN to connect to the internal network. When the VPN is active, the laptop communicates only with the internal network (full tunnel mode). This minimises the risk of the laptop bridging the untrusted wireless network onto the sensitive internal network. In fairness, most firewall configs (even just Windows firewall) stop this anyway.